# PHP: How to validate $_POST variables?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
if ($email!=='ThisMail'){
header ('Location:http://www.mywebsite.com/');
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
}
else{
header ('Location:http://www.google.com/');
exit;
}
?>
```

I am basically collecting information from a form on my website, with `action=form.php` (where this code is saved). I want it so that if the email field on my HTML document where the form is is filled out with a particular email address, `ThisMail`, it will write all the stored data from the form in the file `data.txt` and redirect to the webpage I want.

The other side of the if statement simply redirects the user to another page.

This does not seem to be working for me. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't get it.

Comment: You might want to check for equality (`===`), not inequality (`!==`). Also note that this check is case sensitive. Consider using [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php).

Comment: @Andreas basically take an email input from the user, and if it is a bad email, i.e admin@mywebsite.com then return them to this page, but if it isn't a bad email, i.e !=='theemail@mywebsite.com' then save the email and all other variables from the form on a text document, and redirect them to another page. Isn't very practical I know, but is useful for me.

Comment: @ccKep I don't think that is a problem, as when I run the script it just opens a blank page that is the php file and shows nothing instead of going to the correct web page.

Comment: I'm assuming you have some code before that snippet, eg. actually declaring `$email` ?

Comment: where and how is `$email` defined and its actual value? the question's unclear.

Comment: @ccKep as someone suggested in the answers, and my apologies for neglecting to add this, I have this $email = $_POST['email']; just after <?php but it still doesn't seem to be working, I do not get redirected

Comment: the only possible solution I can provide for what was posted, is to use PHP's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php in order to check for possible errors. Also to make sure that the file has proper permissions to be written to. @EuxLuxed best I can offer for you here.

Comment: so @EuxLuxed any update as to what's (not) going on?

Answer (score 0):

Here, $email is not defined, so you should add this before the if statement:

```
$email = $_POST['email']; // here 'email' is the field name in your HTML page
```

Comment: Theoretically correct, but we don't know what the origin of that variable is. They might even have left it out from the question.

Comment: Apologies for neglecting to add this to my question, I already have this but it still does not appear to be working, I do not get redirected.